# Pick values from MySql database and populate select tag in Struts 2

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jsp, struts2, taglib

I want to pick values from my database `Prodotti1` and populate a dropdown list with them in Struts 2.

I'm using

```
<sql:setDataSource var="ds" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Prodotti1" user="root" password="root"/>
<sql:query dataSource="${ds}" var="result">
    SELECT * from Producer;
</sql:query>

    <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
          <option value='<c:out value="${row.producer_name}"/>'>
          <c:out value="${row.producer_name}"/></option>
    </c:forEach>
```

I want to populate

```
<s:select label="Producer"
    headerKey="-1" headerValue="--Select--"
    list=""
    name="" />
```

But I don't know what to put in `list` field. If I put `%{result.row}` I got this error:

```
The requested list key '%{#result.row}' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use `#attr` which will search the variable in all scopes.

```
<s:select label="Producer"
    headerKey="-1" headerValue="--Select--"
    list="%{#attr.result.rows.{producer_name}}"
    name="producer" />
```